# Is there API/code to get list of ids from kibana visuals,dashboards,charts?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana-7

I want to show charts, visuals(without Kibana UI) generated from Kibana in our project UI dynamically. Is there any API/code to get the list of ids of charts or dashboards from Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kibana [Saved Objects API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api-find.html) in order to retrieve all index patterns, saved searches, visualization and dashboards that are stored in your `.kibana' index.

```
curl -XGET -u 'elastic:password' 'http://<kibana-server>:5601/api/saved_objects/_find?type=visualization&per_page=100&search=*'
```